# Summing 3d numpy array over plane, not axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d numpy array (nx5x5). I want to sum each of the n slices together. So the new shape will be (nx1x1), where each n is just the sum of an individual 5x5 array. Can I do this in numpy without using a loop? np.sum has its axis arguments, but they reshape the array into the wrong shape. I think I may need to call np.sum twice? But I'm having trouble thinking about how to do this. Anybody know the answer?

Comment: Please show an example of how the axis argument led you astray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three different ways of doing it:

1. Use a `tuple` for `axis`:

   ```
   a.sum(axis=(1, 2))
   ```
2. Reshape properly to merge the axes you want to sum over:

   ```
   a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1).sum(axis=1)
   ```
3. Use multiple sums:

   ```
   a.sum(-1).sum(-1)
   ```

   OR

   ```
   a.sum(1).sum(-1)
   ```

   etc.

Comment: Figured this out right as you posted. The tuple axis is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @nrc. In that case, no need to post an answer, especially one with a syntax error. Feel free to select when you are ready.

Answer (score 2):

> np.sum has its axis arguments, but they reshape the array into the wrong shape

Summing is a reduction operation and it makes sense that after reducing in a specific axis (by summing all elements in that axis) that particular dimension is removed. If you don't want that you can pass the optional `keepdims` argument.

```py
values = np.random.randn(3,5,5)
values.sum(axis=(1,2), keepdims=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Think I figured this out, for anyone who is running into the same issue. It turns out you can select two axes from np.sum, making a plane instead of a line. So:

```
np.sum(a, (1,2)
```

Does the trick.